# Change type of property to a subclass in a child class

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an AbstractListFragment class with a property viewModel of type AbstractListViewModel. How can I change the type of this property to a subclass of AbstractListViewModel in a child class of AbstractListFragment

I tried this:

```
abstract class AbstractListViewModel()

abstract class AbstractListFragment() {
   abstract var viewModel : AbstractListViewModel
}

class ChildListViewModel() : AbstractListViewModel()

class ChildListFragment() {
   override lateinit var viewModel : ChildListViewModel
}
```

However, I get:

> Var-property is "ChildListViewModel", which is not type of overriden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code

First, *ChildListFragment* needs to extend *AbstractListFragment* to override its field

```
class ChildListFragment() : AbstractListFragment()
```

Second, you can't override var with subclass of property type because it breaks [Liskov Substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If some method expects *AbstractListFragment*, and you pass *ChildListFragment* there, method could assign some other child of *AbstractListViewModel* to *viewModel*, and *ChildListFragment* would break because it requires exactly *ChildListFragment*

```
class AnotherChild() : AbstractListFragment()

fun someMethod(AbstractListFragment fragment) {
    fragment.viewModel = AnotherChild() // <= here ChildListFragment would expect ChildListViewModel but would get AnotherChild
}

fun main() {
    someMethod(ChildListFragment())
}
```

If you want to return *ChildListViewModel* from *ChildListFragment* you should change *viewModel* to be val

```
abstract class AbstractListFragment() {
    abstract val viewModel : AbstractListViewModel
}

class ChildListFragment() : AbstractListFragment() {
    override val viewModel : ChildListViewModel
}
```

You can use baking lateinit field like the following:

```
class ChildListFragment() : AbstractListFragment() {
    private lateinit var _viewModel: ChildListViewModel

    override val viewModel : ChildListViewModel by lazy {
        _viewModel
    }
}
```

Or you can use some other techniques like MVP (see [Moxy library](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy), for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize your `AbstractListFragment` class with a type of view model:

```
abstract class AbstractListViewModel()

abstract class AbstractListFragment<T : AbstractListViewModel>() {
    abstract var viewModel: T
}

class ChildListViewModel() : AbstractListViewModel()

class ChildListFragment() : AbstractListFragment<ChildListViewModel>() {
    override lateinit var viewModel: ChildListViewModel
}
```